# What is android sdk 'build-tools' directory when exporting to android in godot?

Tags: android, export, godot, godot4, androidexported

I wanted to make android project with godot. So I watched android export tutorial video. But I keep getting error that saying missing Android 'build-tools' directory. I don't even know what 'build-tools' directory is. Please help me :(

[image]

The video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCLYMF32ZBE

I tried to find the location of 'build-tools' directory and see it was really missing. I tried to follow official godot android export tutorial but it turns out that same to the video.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages that are just text. Just include and format the error text into your question.

Comment: The build-tools directory is included in the Android SDK installation directory. Just look into the directory where you had installed Android SDK.